# How to proxy authentication tokens from Firebase to client through Laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I'm refactoring my backend away from Node/Express to PHP/Laravel and the datastore from firebase to mysql. This process will take a while and for a certain time, both old and new backends should live in parallel.

The first step I'm taking is enabling authenticated users from the new backend to access the legacy firebase realtime database. I already can use user credentials (email/password) to log them in from my new backend into firebase using the package [kreait/laravel-firebase](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase/).

This is how I authenticate users in firebase:

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $fUser = app('firebase.auth')->signInWithEmailAndPassword($request->email, $request->password);
    // rest of login...
}
```

`signInWithEmailAndPassword()` returns an `SignInResult` object containing all tokens coming from Firebase.

```json
{
    -idToken: "long token here"
    -accessToken: ...
    -refreshToken: "long token here"
    -ttl: ...
    -data: ...
    -firebaseUserId: ...
    ...
}
```

So far, so good. My problem though, is that I don't know how to pass those tokens back to the client so my users will be automatically logged-in in the frontend app when authenticated in the new backend.

Any help is more than appreciated!

Comment: make a channel between expressjs and laravel that only those two can use (localhost to localhost if both on the same machine) and use that to register tokens with expressJs into  laravel DB, then redirect the user with that token to laravel and since it's a valid token for laravel (and contains all the data required) it should log the user in and unvalidate the token to prevent reuse.

Comment: Both systems are way apart in a bigger infrastructure. The only way of communicating between them is through API's

Comment: then restrict communication between them with a shared secret by encrypting data and/or restricting IP, there is way many ways to secure a channel between both installation